# Remove objects from each object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to improve the table performance with a large dataset by removing all nested objects which the table doesn't use. I don't want to name the keys because they will vary from dataset to dataset. This needs to be a reusable helper function that removes objects based on `typeof` rather than a key.

Example data:

```
const data = [
  { test: 1, notes: [] },
  { test: 2, notes: [] },
  { test: 3, notes: [] }
];
```

expected result

```
[
  { test: 1 },
  { test: 2 },
  { test: 3 }
];
```

What I've tried:

```
  const simpleRows = (arr) => {
    var rows = arr.map(({ notes, ...keepAttrs }) => keepAttrs);
    return rows;
  };

  const rows = simpleRows(data) // This works but I have hardcoded the key 'notes' which I don't want
```

What is the most efficient way to remove all objects from each object in an array of objects in a large dataset (~10000 objects in the array) without hardcoding the key, and without an external library?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to remove every property that is an array?

Comment: @RameshReddy yes every property that is an array from each object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the entries of each object and create a new object from the filtered entries:

```js
const data = [
  { test: 1, notes: [] },
  { test: 2, notes: [] },
  { test: 3, notes: [] }
]
const result = data.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => !Array.isArray(v))))
console.log(result)
```